# TimePickerDialog не корректно работает в режиме 24h

Tags: android, время, kotlin

Суть в том, что когда в `TimePicker` выбираешь 10:30, в `Calendar` записывается 22:30, иногда случается обратное, иногда работает правильно.

```
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)


        val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())


        eventStartTimeTextView?.setOnClickListener {
            val timePicker = TimePickerDialog(this@NewEventActivity, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
                startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay)
                startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                Log.d(MyApplication.TAG, timeFormat.format(startDateCalendar.time))
                eventStartTimeTextView?.text = timeFormat.format(startDateCalendar.time)
            }, hour, minute, true)
            timePicker.show()
        }
```

Логи конечно немного бесполезные, но тем не менее. Здесь я 6 раз устанавливал 15:30 в `timePicker`

```
06-19 20:50:38.244 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 03:30
06-19 20:50:42.461 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 15:30
06-19 20:50:46.050 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 03:30
06-19 20:50:50.260 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 15:30
06-19 20:50:53.362 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 03:30
06-19 20:50:57.043 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 15:30
06-19 20:51:00.444 1557-1557/com.likhanov.mainwork D/tag: 03:30
```

Как видно время то 03, то 15. Тестировал и на реальном ус-ве, и на эмуляторе

Comment: видимо определяется в зависимости от `Locale` текущего устройства?

Comment: логи для одного и того же устройства, по времени записей видно, что тест проводился в одно время. Да и по мимо вывода в логи, я в `TextView` тоже заношу выбранное время, там локали нет, выводится также как попало

Comment: у вас в одном случае `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, а во втором: `Calendar.HOUR`. Может в этом дело?

Comment: действительно, невнимательность. Если хотите, оформите ответ, я приму

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В одном случае вы используете `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, в другом - `Calendar.HOUR`.

Calendar.HOUR показывает часы 0-11:

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY - имеет 24х часовой формат:

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

[Источник](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR)